# Find a vector function that represents the curve of intersection of $x^2+y^2=4$ and $z=x$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Find a vector function that represents the curve of intersection of $x^2+y^2=4$ and $z=x$

I changed $x^2+y^2=4$ to $4sin^2\theta + 4cos^2\theta = 4$ so $x=2cos\theta$ and $y=2sin\theta$ and then $z=2cos\theta$

so my overall answer was $R= <2cos\theta,2sin\theta,2cos\theta>$

i got $0$ points on this problem on my exam so i'm assuming i did the problem completely wrong.

Comment: I just graphed your answer in my head and it looks good to me.

Comment: really? i wish i would have brought it up to my professor when i had the chance.

Comment: Yes. $x^2+y^2=4$ is a cylinder oriented around the $z$-axis of radius $2$ and $z=x$ is a vertical plane passing through it diagonally. It is elementary that the intersection is an ellipse.

Comment: If you specify that $\theta$ is in $(0, 2\pi)$, the answer is correct.